# Would it be possible to use a device pumping air out of it to liquify the sand around it?

Tags: air

The question has to do with the demonstration done by Mark Rober when he made a hot tub by releasing air from below the sand upward at a rate that would increase the amount of air between the sand particles causing it to behave like water. The part I have a question about is if you were to create a device that would intake air from above the sand and disperse it out from the device at the same rate would it liquify the sand around it or would it not work due to the air needing to rise or something similar? (I'm not sure what kind of physics if any would be used to figure this out, any info would be helpful)

Comment: This is called a fluidized bed.

Comment: Air flows can be different for systems that suck air vs systems that blow air. It is hard to say anything specific without details (and details would make it an engineering project more than a quick question.) But there is no reason in principal you couldn't do it.

Comment: This is a very poorly formulated question. =(